Buttons are not clickable in some angles after adding BillBoardComponent in visionOS 2
Hi I have set up some attachments in SwiftUI code using a custom component added to transforms entities in RealityComposer Pro. These attachment have a button too. Everything works fine. Since I need a billboard effect for my attachments, I added
guard let component = entity.components[PointsOfInterestRunTimeComponent.self] else {return}
            
guard let attachmentEntity = attachments.entity(for: component.attachmentTag) else { return }
            
guard attachmentEntity.parent == nil else {return}
                            
var billBoard = BillboardComponent()
billBoard.rotationAxis = [0,1,0]
attachmentEntity.components.set(billBoard)

content.add(attachmentEntity)
attachmentEntity.setPosition([0.0, 0.5, 0.0], relativeTo: entity)

And this is my attachment view.
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
    Text(name)
        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "Name", in: animation)
                    .font(titleFont)
                
    Text(description)
        .font(descriptionFont)
    Button("Done") {
        viewModel.arrows.remove(at: 0)
    }
}

My problem is after adding billboard component, sometimes the button inside my view is not clickable. It works only in the initial position of the player. how can I resolve this?
